# How to speed up fixture loading time on python unittests on macOS?

Tags: python, django, macos, python-unittest, fixtures

I had fixture file for a model, which has about 900 objects. While those objects were loaded from one fixture file, tests were quite fast. But I had to split that fixture into *one-fixture-per-object* principle.

And now, when I am loading all fixtures on tests, it takes about 40 secs on every setUp on *macOS*, but on *Linux* it didn't do significant difference on loading time.

I have created a `CoreBaseTestCase` class which gets all fixtures from directory and puts it to variable, then it provides those fixtures names to `fixtures` variable.

```
class CoreBaseTestCase(TestCase):
    many_fixtures = [os.listdir('path/to/fixtures')]

    fixtures = \
        ['fixture1.json',
         'fixture2.json'] + \
        many_fixtures
```

What could be the solution on shortening fixtures loading time on macOS?

on *macOS* `setUp` takes `45.77s`, on *Linux* `setUp` takes `7.4s`

For example, the test `test_something` would take 6 times more time on *macOS* than on *Linux*:

```
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = CoreBaseTestCase.fixtures + ['fixture3.json']

    def test_something(self):
        a = 1
        self.assertEqual(a, 1)
```